# Know someone who can check my mysql workbench Error code 1215?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When connecting the flight table books table and company I get the error 1215.  I have no problems connecting the other tables.  Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
create database aviacion; 
use aviacion; 

create Table Compañia( 
  Codigo char(8) NOT NULL, 
  Nombre varchar(15), 
  Volumen_venta decimal(10,0) 
); 

create Table Pais( 
  Codigo char(8) NOT NULL, 
  Nombre varchar(10), 
  Idioma varchar(10), 
  Moneda varchar(10) 
); 

create Table Avion( 
  Nombre varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
  Consumo_gas int(8), 
  Cantidad_asientos int(25) 
); 

create Table Viaje( 
  Codigo char(8) NOT NULL, 
  Lugar varchar(10), 
  Destino varchar(10), 
  Cantidad_km int(8) 
); 

create Table Vuelo( 
  Precio decimal(10,0) NOT NULL, 
  Tiempo_duracion datetime NOT NULL 
); 

Alter Table Compañia Add Primary Key (Codigo); 
Alter Table Pais Add Primary Key (Codigo); 
Alter Table Avion Add Primary Key (Nombre); 
Alter Table Viaje Add Primary Key (Codigo); 
Alter Table Vuelo Add Primary Key (Precio); 

Alter Table Pais Add Foreign Key (Codigo) References Compañia(Codigo); 
Alter Table Avion Add Foreign Key (Nombre) References Pais(Codigo); 
Alter Table Viaje Add Foreign Key (Codigo) References Avion(Nombre); 
Alter Table Vuelo Add Foreign Key (Precio) References Viaje(Codigo); 
Alter Table Vuelo Add Foreign Key (Precio) References Compañia(Codigo);
```

Comment: BTW You should never mix CHAR and VARCHAR in one Table

Comment: Is there any evidence for that advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try create database without the foreign keys and check if it works.

When you try to add the foreign key to this part

```
ALTER TABLE Vuelo ADD FOREIGN KEY (Precio) REFERENCES Compañia(Codigo);
```

You're using a different Datatype.

`Precio` is a Decimal Datatype, `Compañia(Codigo)` is a char, but Foreign Keys must have to have the same Datatype.